# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_name' of null

Tags: angular, indexeddb, angular5

After clearing browsing data and running project I am getting below error

> "jsstore.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_name' of
>   null"

while creating indexeddb using jsstore.

[image]

Comment: somehow browser data is not cleared completely. JsStore maintains one special db for storing meta keys named as KeyStore. Somehow the meta key db is messed up. Remove again everything or try in incognito to see if everything is good.

Comment: Thanks,Is any other solution for that?

Comment: When you want to delete db - use dropDb api (http://jsstore.net/tutorial/drop_database). You can also use clear api if you want to just clear data from your table.

Comment: if user clearing browser data.my site will not work some times right?can i fix this

Comment: No, it will work. It must be something particular case, where it is failing. I clear the browser data and reloaded page and it worked. Please mention the steps to generate the above scenario.

Comment: just cleared browsing data then  got error while running again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163386/discussion-between-ujjwal-kumar-gupta-and-kamalav).